# What is $ in Haskell, and how to apply functions to functions

Tags: function, haskell, operator-precedence

I'm doing Project Euler with Haskell, and found something to learn when completing [the very first problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1). Here's my code:

```
isValid x = (mod x 3 == 0) || (mod x 5 == 0)
listValid :: Integer -> [Integer]
listValid n = [x | x <- [1..n-1], isValid x]
```

The function `listValid` will get all the positive integers less than `n` that are divisble by either 3 or 5.  Easy enough.

```
*Main> listValid 10
[3,5,6,9]
```

Now I need to sum them. I figure the sum function is the right way to do this. What I don't understand is why the first two versions work, and then third doesn't.

```
*Main> sum (listValid 10)
23
*Main> sum $ listValid 10
23
*Main> sum listValid 10

<interactive>:4:5:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Integer]’ with ‘a0 -> t’
    Expected type: Integer -> a0 -> t
      Actual type: Integer -> [Integer]
    Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:4:1)
    In the first argument of ‘sum’, namely ‘listValid’
    In the expression: sum listValid 10
```

Is this an order of operations problem, where I need to wrap in parentheses to assert which function should be applied first? And if so, what is the `$` doing in the second version?

Comment: "Is this an order of operations problem, where I need to wrap in parentheses to assert which function should be applied first?" *yes.* "And if so, what is the `$` doing in the second version?" *just that*. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's about associativity. Function application is left-associative, so `sum listValid 10` is equivalent to `(sum listValid) 10`, not `sum (listValid 10)`. And if you think about it, it has to be that way: If you define `add x y = x+y`, you wouldn't want `add 1 2` to be equivalent to `add (1 2)`.

So the issue here is that in `sum listValid 10`, it doesn't see `listValid 10` as the argument to `sum`; it sees `listValid` as the argument to `sum` and then `10` as the argument to `sum listValid`.

`$` resolves this issue because it's an infix operator and it's perfectly clear that `sum` is its left operand and `listValid 10` is its right operand (keeping in mind that function application has higher precedence than any infix operator, so it can't be seen as `(sum $ listValid) 10`).

Comment: It's more about precedence than associativity, or `sum $ listValid 10` would still try to evaluate `sum $ listValid` before applying the result to `10`. (Plus, the right associativity only becomes relevant if multiple `$` operators are used as once; `f $ g $ h` is the same as `f $ (g $ h)`, not `(f $ g) $ h`).

Comment: because of the *associativity* issue with `f g x`, *precedence* comes into play in `f $ g x`.

Answer (score 3):

Function application `f x` is the highest-priority operation (and left-associative), so that

```
sum listValid 10
```

is equivalent to `(sum listValid) 10`.

The `$` operator, on the other hand, has the lowest precedence possible (and is right-associative, although that isn't relevant here), so that

```
sum $ listValid 10
```

is implicitly the same as `sum $ (listValid 10)`, not `(sum $ listValid) 10`. Thus, it is commonly used to eliminate parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `f $ x`, you write in fact `($) f x`, with [**`($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) a function. This function is [defined as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%24):

> ```
> ($) :: forall r a (b :: TYPE r). (a -> b) -> a -> b
> f $ x = f x
> ```

The above does not look very impressive. If you thus write `f $ x`, it is equivalent to `f x`, so then why write a `$` anyway? Because this operator has [precedence 0](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.2). It thus means that if you write:

```
f $ x+2
```

it is interpreted as:

```
($) f (x+2)
```

and thus:

```
f (x+2)
```

without the need to write brackets.

Going back to your question, if you write:

```
sum $ listValid 10
```

this is parsed as:

```
($) (sum) (listValid 10)
```

and thus functionally equivalent to:

```
sum (listValid 10)
```

If you however write:

```
sum listValid 10
```

Haskell interprets this as:

```
(sum listValid) 10
```

now the `sum` of a function with type `Integer -> [Integer]` does not make sense, [**`sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) should take a list of `Num`erical values, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

Function application is left-associative, so

```
f x y
```

is parsed as:

```
(f x) y
```

However, function application has higher precedence than any infix operator, so

```
f x $ g y
```

is parsed as:

```
(f x) $ (g y)
```

In particular, you have:

```
sum listValid 10 = (sum listValid) 10
sum $ listValid 10 = sum $ (listValid 10) = sum (listValid 10)
```